# Why did an attribute disappear once I applied "mapValues()" to an RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with the Stack Overflow public data dump and trying to find out whether or not a given question has one of the top 10 common tags. The data looks like this `<row Body="..." Id="1740" Tags="<machine-learning><spark><regression>" ... />`.

First, I identified the 10 most common tags from the training data.

```
import os
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "temp")

def localpath(path):
    return 'file://' + str(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)) + '/' + path

class Record(object):
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        self.attr = attributes

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, line):
        attributes = xmlparser(line)
        return cls(attributes)

def isRow(line):
    return "<row" in line

tags_10 = sc.textFile(localpath('spark-stats-data/allPosts/*')) \
            .filter(lambda x: isRow(x)) \
            .map(Record.parse) \
            .filter(lambda x: x.attr is not None and x.attr.get('Tags')) \
            .flatMap(lambda x: (x.attr['Tags'].strip('<>').split('><'))) \
            .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
            .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) \
            .map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])) \
            .sortByKey(ascending = False) \
            .take(10)

tags_10_words = [v for k, v in tags_10]
topwords_BV = sc.broadcast(tags_10_words)
```

When I'm trying to parse `Body`, `Tags`, and `Id` from the data, I encountered a problem.

```
import mwparserfromhell as mwp

def bodyParser(body):
    try:
        return mwp.parse(body).strip_code().replace('\n',' ')
    except:
        return ''

train = sc.textFile(localpath("spark-stats-data/train/*")) \
          .filter(lambda x: isRow(x)) \
          .map(Record.parse) \
          .filter(lambda x: x.attr is not None and x.attr.get('Tags') and x.attr.get('Body') and x.attr.get('Id')) \
          .map(lambda x: (bodyParser(x.attr['Body']), x.attr['Id'], x.attr['Tags'].strip('<>').split('><'))) \
          .filter(lambda x: x[0]) \
          .mapValues(lambda x: [int(word in x) for word in topwords_BV.value]) \
          .map(lambda x: [x[0]] + x[1])
```

The problem is that I only saw the text in `Body` and information on `Tags` but not the `Id` attribute (e.g., see `train.take(2)[1]` below). Why did this happen and how can I get `Id` out of the data?

```
('I am carrying out an analysis using a 4$\\times$2 crosstab. I found an overall significant difference but I would like to find if there are significant differences among the 4 groups.  Is there a way to carry out these multiple comparisons?',
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I suspected that `.mapValues()` is the culprit because if I remove it, I can see `Id`:

```
test_out = sc.textFile(localpath("spark-stats-data/train/*")) \
             .filter(lambda x: isRow(x)) \
             .map(Record.parse) \
             .filter(lambda x: x.attr is not None and x.attr.get('Tags') and x.attr.get('Body') and x.attr.get('Id')) \
             .map(lambda x: (bodyParser(x.attr['Body']), x.attr['Tags'].strip('<>').split('><'), x.attr['Id'])) \
             .filter(lambda x: x[0]) \
             .take(2)
```

This is from `test_out[1]`:

```
('I am carrying out an analysis using a 4$\\times$2 crosstab. I found an overall significant difference but I would like to find if there are significant differences among the 4 groups.  Is there a way to carry out these multiple comparisons?',
 ['chi-squared', 'multiple-comparisons'],
 '114743')
```

So my question is, how can I retain `Id` after the applying the `.mapValues` step? I greatly appreciate your help!

**Additional question:** If I want to sort by `Id` (ascending), what's the best place to add that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem!

The basic idea is first grouping `Body` and `Id` together so each row would be like ((`Body`, `Id`), `Tags`) and then applying `.mapValues()`. After getting the mapping for `Tags`, I did some additional unpacking to return results in the form of `[Body, Id, 0, 1, ...., 0]` (12 elements: body text, question ID, whether it has each of the 10 most common tags).

```
train = sc.textFile(localpath("spark-stats-data/train/*")) \
          .filter(lambda x: isRow(x)) \
          .map(Record.parse) \
          .filter(lambda x: x.attr is not None and x.attr.get('Tags') and x.attr.get('Body') and x.attr.get('Id')) \
          .map(lambda x: (bodyParser(x.attr['Body']), x.attr['Tags'].strip('<>').split('><'), x.attr['Id'])) \
          .filter(lambda x: x[0]) \
          .map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[2]), x[1])) \
          .mapValues(lambda x: [int(word in x) for word in topwords_BV.value]) \
          .map(lambda x: [x[0][0]] + [x[0][1]] + x[1])
```